# Installing Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, yum

```
./configure --user=boxflux 
            --group=boxflux 
            --prefix=/usr/local/nginx-1.3.0                    
            --with-pcre=/usr/lib64 
            --with-md5=/usr/lib64 
            --with-sha1=/usr/lib64 
            --with-zlib=/usr/lib64 
            --with-libatomic=/usr/lib64 
            --with-openssl=/usr/lib64 | grep 'not found'
checking for sys/filio.h ... not found
checking for /dev/poll ... not found
checking for kqueue ... not found
checking for crypt() ... not found
checking for F_READAHEAD ... not found
checking for F_NOCACHE ... not found
checking for directio() ... not found
checking for dlopen() ... not found
checking for SO_SETFIB ... not found
checking for SO_ACCEPTFILTER ... not found
checking for setproctitle() ... not found
checking for POSIX semaphores ... not found
checking for struct dirent.d_namlen ... not found
```

I have a problem installing nginx.. 
I've already installed gcc, pcre*, zlib*, openssl* by using 'yum'

What's problem with my configuration? 
By the way, my computer is 64bit centos6 and I'm now installing nginx 1.3.0 (development version)

--------- ADDITOIN -----------------------

I forgot to mention that it was even worse than I added those --with-*=DIR...
When I run a line of code kolbyjack gave me, the result is..

```
./configure --user=boxflux --group=boxflux --prefix=/usr/local/nginx-1.3.0 |grep 'not found'
checking for sys/filio.h ... not found
checking for /dev/poll ... not found
checking for kqueue ... not found
checking for crypt() ... not found
checking for F_READAHEAD ... not found
checking for F_NOCACHE ... not found
checking for directio() ... not found
checking for dlopen() ... not found
checking for SO_SETFIB ... not found
checking for SO_ACCEPTFILTER ... not found
checking for setproctitle() ... not found
checking for POSIX semaphores ... not found
checking for struct dirent.d_namlen ... not found
checking for PCRE JIT support ... not found
checking for system md library ... not found
checking for system md5 library ... not found
checking for sha1 in system md library ... not found
```

Since I am a newbie on centos6.. I really have no any idea on this issue..
please help me..

Comment: Why do you think that you have any problem?
Ok, you have no kqueue in the system. Of course, you haven't, because your system isn't FreeBSD.

Comment: Thanks VBart~ when I run "sudo yum install *kqueue*", the result is that "sudo yum install *kqueue*" 
How can I install kqueue on my centos6? please, be understanding.. becuase I am a newbie on centos.

Comment: You cannot install kqueue on centos6, because its a *BSD kernel feature.

If you want kqueue support, you chose the wrong OS. NetBSD, OpenBSD, DragonflyBSD, and Mac OS X have kqueue support, but Linux haven't. Probably, you can run centos with bsd kernel, but it's a bad idea.

Nginx doesn't need all these features to run. Different operating systems have different features, and NGINX just wants to know which ones are supported by your system.

Comment: "... not found" doesn't mean bad or error. On different systems you will have different "notfounds". When you set all these "--with-*=", you just swiched off some checks.

Comment: Thanks really really VBart.. I've just found that they are not critical issues as you said.. ㅠㅠ.. Wow.. by the way, you're so smart! Thanks a lot Bvart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `./configure --help`:

```
--with-pcre=DIR                    set path to PCRE library sources
--with-md5=DIR                     set path to md5 library sources
--with-sha1=DIR                    set path to sha1 library sources
--with-zlib=DIR                    set path to zlib library sources
--with-libatomic=DIR               set path to libatomic_ops library sources
--with-openssl=DIR                 set path to OpenSSL library sources
```

If you read the help text, each of those options set the directory for the library *sources*, not the installed version of the library.  If the library is already installed on the system, nginx should automatically find it during configure.  If it's installed in a nonstandard location, you should use `--with-cc-opt` and `--with-ld-opt` to set the include and library paths for nginx to search.  Since you've installed all the libs via yum, I expect that all you really need is:

```
./configure --user=boxflux --group=boxflux --prefix=/usr/local/nginx-1.3.0
```

Answer (score 11):

Often times, I'd prefer not to use "after market" builds from src but instead use the native
CentOS packages.

The "PCRE Library Not Found" error can also be caused when the pcre package is installed but not the pcre-devel package.

Merely, 'yum install pcre-devel' and rerun ./configure.